# Opening and closing tag Regex

Tags: regex, tags, latex, matching

I've been desperately looking for a Regex expression that does the following :

Find the pattern:

```
$$ some text $$.
```

- The dollar signs included
- There might be others `$` in the expressions but it should only match an opening `$$` with the first closing `$$`
- There might be multiple occurrences of this pattern in the text and there should all be recognized.

Example :

```
*Il y a une equation juste ici $$x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ et elle vient de se terminer. Une autre là $$ \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-8b}} $$ jusqu'à là. Il y a une equation juste ici $$x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ et elle vient de se terminer. Une autre là $$ \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-8b}} $$ jusqu'à là $$ hey $$*
```

Does anyone knows a formula for this ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I am assuming the bold highlights what you want. Can you confirm? In which case, try [this](https://regex101.com/r/03xzCR/2)

Comment: @pkpkpk Yes !! Thank you very much it's perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
\$\$.*?\$\$
```

- `\$\$` Matches two `\$` characters.
- `.*?` Matches anything as few times as possible.
- `\$\$` Matches two `\$` characters.

The matches therefore are:

- `$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$`
- `$$ \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-8b}} $$`
- `$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$`
- `$$ \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-8b}} $$`
- `$$ hey $$`

You can test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/03xzCR/2).

Comment: i didnt know about the .*? matches as few times as possible, this was what i needed in my regex to select what i needed. Thanks.